# Importar banco de dados sqlite já povoado

Tags: android, banco-de-dados, android-studio, sqlite

Estou fazendo um app necessita fazer apenas consultas num banco de dados. Como se trata de uma quantidade muito grande dados, acho que seria contra produtivo alimentar esse banco de dados usando um *insertOrThrow* pra cada item de uma tabela. Não sei qual a melhor forma de realizar essa operação, então estou fazendo um procedimento meio que "às cegas" aqui, mas não está sendo muito efetivo. Para inserir esses dados usei o utilitário *SqliteStudio*. Alguém aí já fez uma operação deste tipo? Qual database manager sugere para uso? Estou tendo dificuldades para importar esse banco gerado no manager para dentro do projeto do Android Studio. Pelo que pesquisei, é necessário criar uma pasta chamada *Assets* no projeto e colocar o banco de dados lá dentro.

Sobre a importação, encontrei informações para usar a classe *InputStream*, mas não consegui carregar as informações do arquivo. Durante a execução, no procedimento para listar os dados, entra no *cath* e diz que não foi encontrada tabela no banco.
O objetivo maior desta pergunta é obter conselhos de como realizar uma operação de inserção de grande volume de dados em um banco de dados e usá-lo para consulta através do Android Studio. Quem puder contribuir, agradeço. Abração!

Comment: Acho que este [link](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/) pode ajudar...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boa tarde Fabio, acredito que fazer os insert com `insertOrThrow` não seja problema não. Eu construí uma aplicação que a primeira sincronização ele insere cerca de 40 mil registros.

Não encontrei nem um problema referente a isso até agora, pois faço este processo demorado apenas a primera vez.

Está rodando em dezenas de aparelhos já faz uns 20 meses.

Comment: Boa tarde, Eduardo! No caso, você está fazendo a inclusão de cada registro dentro do seu código? A manutenção não fica complicada?

Comment: Por exemplo, você fez algo desse tipo para cada um dos registros? 
ContentValues valor = new ContentValues();
valor.put("NOME", "Fabio");
valor.put("TEELFONE", "000000");
conexao.insertOrThrow("CLIENTE", null, valores);

Comment: isso, corretamente. Só que eu tenho um método que tem como parâmetro o objeto. Ai só instancio um o objecto e chamo o método.